# Resources for learning Spanish / Recursos para aprender español

Tags: recursos, diccionarios, aprendizaje, preguntas-canónicas

> This is a [canonical question](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2505/1674) / Esta es una [pregunta canónica](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2505/1674)

This is a specifically created Community Wiki which gathers resources for learning Spanish and it has been approved by the Community itself.

#### Alphabetical Index

Click the links to visit the specific section with the resources.

| Section | description |
| --- | --- |
| [Audio pronunciation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23623/13628) |  |
| [Corpora](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/24314/13628) |  |
| [Courses](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/40588/1674) | Set of courses to take online |
| [Dictionaries (online)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23618/1674) | Stand-alone or dictionary files for you to use on your computer. |
| [Dictionaries (hard-back or paper-back)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/24315/13628) |  |
| [How to learn Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/24098/1674) |  |
| [Lists of words](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23617/resources-for-learning-spanish/24298#24298) |  |
| [Mobile apps](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23645/1674) |  |
| [Podcasts](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23635/9385) |  |
| [Television](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23630/1674) <sub>[Netflix](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23644/1674)</sub> |  |
| [Thesauri](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23632/1674) |  |
| [Websites](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/24313/1674) |  |
| [Writing](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/37575/1674) |  |
| [Other reference resources](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/24312/9385) |  |

---

It should be clear that **the resources are not written by one user or only by the mods, but *by whoever wants to contribute***.

Please **don't add new answers unless a whole new category is needed. Just edit the appropriate answer/section to include the resource(s) you want to be listed**. If you have concerns, questions, [post a meta question](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/), so we don't clutter the comments, but you can link your meta question from the comments.

Questions regarding such resources **will be closed as duplicates of this one**, except for very specific requests not yet included in any of the current answers (ask on [Meta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/) if you're unsure about your question). As read in [Resources for Learning Spanish](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2514/) in Meta, if you pose a question asking for resources not yet covered by answers to this one, we may leave your question open for some days while it gathers answers; once it's answered, we may move its answers here and close it as a duplicate of this one.

#### How this page is organized

- Each answer covers a particular category.
- Include a short summary with each link, describing how it is useful or who it is useful to
- Keep your entries as succinct as possible to maintain a easy-to-follow list format.
- Don't include links to any illegal/copyright violating content, or sites that host such content.
- If you are a developer/provider of the resource you are adding, follow our community [rules](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) on self-promotion by including text similar to "developed/maintained by [your user account link](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/1674/fedorqui)" to the resource description.
- Comments here will be fairly aggressively moderated to preserve the presentation of the list. If you have a larger comment or complaint, either talk to a moderator in the chatroom or open a meta question.

*Note: new rules could be added in the future.*

Answer (score 15):

## Dictionaries (online)

---

### Dictionaries by the Real Academia Española (RAE)

- The *Diccionario de la lengua española* and the *Diccionario panhispánico de dudas* are both accessible from the main page of the [Real Academia Española](http://www.rae.es/) (RAE) web site.
- [*Diccionario de la lengua española* (DLE)](http://dle.rae.es/)
- [*Diccionario panhispánico de dudas* (DPD)](http://lema.rae.es/dpd) (2005 edition)
- [*Diccionario de americanismos* (DAMER)](http://lema.rae.es/damer)
- You can also access those from the main page of the [Asociación de Academias de la Lengua Española (ASALE)](http://www.asale.org/) web site.

### Monolingual Spanish dictionaries

- [*Diccionario de la lengua Alkona*](http://www.diclib.com/cgi-bin/d1.cgi?l=es&base=alkonageneral&page=showindex), indexed search only.

  - DicLib allows [searching by word](http://www.diclib.com/cgi-bin/d.cgi?page=search&l=es&category=cat4) too, but for this it uses many other dictionaries besides the Alkona. There's a link to them in **Specialized dictionaries**.
- [VOX and Larousse dictionaries](https://www.diccionarios.com/).
- [Diccionario CLAVE](http://clave.smdiccionarios.com/app.php).
- WordReference uses the [Espasa-Calpe dictionary (2005 edition)](https://www.wordreference.com/definicion/) to search word definitions.
- [*Enciclopedia Espasa* online search](http://espasa.planetasaber.com/default.asp).
- [es.thefreedictionary.com](https://es.thefreedictionary.com)
- [Lexico (Oxford)](https://www.lexico.com/es) choose *Spanish* in the dropdown

### Regional monolingual dictionaries

- [Diccionario breve de mexicanismos de Guido Gómez de Silva (Academia Mexicana de la Lengua)](https://www.academia.org.mx/obras/obras-de-consulta-en-linea/diccionario-breve-de-mexicanismos-de-guido-gomez-de-silva)

### Bilingual dictionaries

- [Merriam-Webster's Spanish Central](http://www.spanishcentral.com)
- [Linguee](http://www.linguee.com/english-spanish) - Includes definitions and many naturally occurring usage examples, side by side.
- [Wiktionary](https://www.wiktionary.org/)
- [PONS](https://en.pons.com/translate)
- [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/browse/spanish-english/)
- [WordReference](https://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp)
- [Spanishdict.com](https://www.spanishdict.com/dictionary)

- [Lexico (Oxford)](https://www.lexico.com/es) choose *Spanish-English* or *English-Spanish* in the dropdown

### Specialized dictionaries

- [*Diccionario del español **jurídico** (DEJ)*](http://dej.rae.es/) (accesible also from the [RAE web](http://www.rae.es/)'s main page).
- *[Enclave de ciencia](https://enclavedeciencia.rae.es/inicio)*. A site to check the meaning of science-related words. It includes in one web site the words marked in the DLE as related to any science field, plus the [AETER dictionary](https://aeter.org/), the [Dicciomed](https://dicciomed.usal.es) from the Salamanca University, and the [Spanish Dictionary of Engineering](http://diccionario.raing.es/es) from the Royal Engineering Academy.
- [*Diccionario **etimológico** español en línea*](http://etimologias.dechile.net/). A Chilean Spanish etymology dictionary.
- [*Epilex*](http://medicine.dundee.ac.uk/studying-populations-epilex) is a free tool for translation of terms in **epidemiology** between nine languages including Spanish and English. Windows only. (Also includes Catalan and Portuguese.)
- [*Nuevo diccionario histórico del español*](http://web.frl.es/DH) (NDHE). Information on the **history of words**.
- [*Fichero de la RAE*](http://web.frl.es/fichero.html). Cards with notes on words that may or may not have ended up being accepted to the official dictionary. Useful to check **alternative, deprecated, or regional meanings of words**.
- [Diccionario Español de Ingeniería (DEI)](http://diccionario.raing.es/es). Made by the Real Academia de Ingeniería. Lets you make exact or approximate searchs of **engineering** terms, as well as filter by field of knowledge.
- [Jergas de Habla Hispana](http://www.jergasdehablahispana.org/). Single-person project to build a dictionary of Spanish **slang words**. You can search by word or by country.
- [Glosario de Terminología informática](http://www.tugurium.com/gti). Single-person project to build a glossary about **IT terms and related engineering topics**. English-Spanish. Started offline in the 80s, went online in 2003.

- [DicLib offers a ton of technical Spanish dictionaries](http://www.diclib.com/cgi-bin/d.cgi?l=es&page=dicts).
- [Universidad de Oviedo's compilation of Spanish dictionaries](http://www6.uniovi.es/links/idiomas.html).
- [Wikilengua en Español also has a list of dictionaries](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Lista_de_diccionarios_en_Internet).
- [Ictioterm](http://www.ictioterm.es/glosario_alfabetico_nombres_vernaculos.php), glossary of common names of fishes from the Andalusian coast, with surprisingly elaborate etymologies (for a fish glossary, I mean).

### Other dictionaries

- [Nuevo tesoro lexicográfico de la lengua española](http://ntlle.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUILoginNtlle) (NTLLE), a dictionary of dictionaries (both monolingual and bilingual) that compiles a wide selection of works that define the lexical heritage of the Spanish language, and covering the last 500 years.
- [Mapa de diccionarios](https://www.rae.es/obras-academicas/diccionarios/mapa-de-diccionarios-0). Check simultaneously six editions from the academic dictionary (editions 1780, 1817, 1884, 1925, 1992 and 2001).
- [Iedra](http://iedra.es). An "inverse dictionary" where you can find a Spanish word provided that you know its meaning.
- [Goodrae](http://recursosdidacticos.es/goodrae/info.php). An alternative interface to RAE's online dictionary (DLE) that let you search by lemma and turned every word into a clickable link to the corresponding definition, in a time when the DLE didn't (this functionality has long since been implemented in the DLE too). Goodrae also functions as an inverse dictionary.

Answer (score 12):

## Audio pronunciation

- [Forvo](https://forvo.com/languages/es/) contains thousands of Spanish words pronounced by natives.
- The [Google translator](https://translate.google.es/) can read aloud any Spanish phrase you type in, with a synthesized voice, as well as attempting to do machine translations.
- [eSpeak](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/) is a free, open source tool (must be installed locally) to convert text to speech. The voice is rather mechanical, but it can also be made to produce reasonably accurate IPA transcriptions.
- [RhinoSpike](https://rhinospike.com/) connects you with native speakers of Spanish (and many other languages) who will record your requested text as audio. In exchange, you do the same for those learning your native language.
- [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com) lets you change the speed at which videos play, a feature that can be used to practice your listening. [Quoting julodnik](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23613/13628): *"You can set the speed to 50% of the normal speed, the pitch of the voice remains unchanged. I try to get familiar with the speech at that speed and then increase the speed gradually until reaching normal speed."*

Answer (score 12):

## Television

| Source | Country | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [Corporación de Radio y Televisión Española](http://www.rtve.es) | Spain | State-owned public corporation that assumed the indirect management of the Spanish public radio and television service (RTVE). Its web site hosts several Spanish channels being broadcasted live (including *La1*, *La2*, *Clan*, *24h* and *Teledeporte*), and lots of contents on demand (series, documentaries, cartoons and others, for all ages). |
| [Historia de nuestro cine](http://www.rtve.es/alacarta/videos/historia-de-nuestro-cine/) | Spain | Spanish films with an introduction by experts. |
| [Pluto.tv](https://pluto.tv/) | - |  |
| [Plex.tv](https://www.plex.tv) | - | Free films online |
| [Atresplayer](https://www.atresplayer.com) | Spain | *Atresmedia*'s service for both live and on-demand streaming of its contents (including the Spanish channels *Antena3* and *laSexta*). |
| [Mitele](https://www.mitele.es) | Spain | *Mediaset España*'s service for both live and on-demand streaming of its contents (including the Spanish channels *Tele5* and *cuatro*). |

### Regional

I you are interested in listening to the way people speak Spanish in the different regions search for the public TV internet streaming for each country. Some examples:

- Argentina

  - [Television Pública Argentina](http://www.tvpublica.com.ar/vivo/)
  - [TN](http://tn.com.ar/envivo/24hs)
- Colombia:

  - [Radio Nacional de Colombia (audio only)](https://www.radionacional.co/players/radionacional/)
  - [Canal RCN](http://www.canalrcn.com/streamingrcn)
  - [Canal Caracol](https://noticias.caracoltv.com/)
- Perú

  - [Panamericana](https://panamericana.pe/tvenvivo)

### Not regionally specific

- [Latin American & Spanish Videos Freely Available on the Internet: A Guide to Web Sources](http://libguides.library.albany.edu/c.php?g=536813&p=3674910)

Comment: A good series produced by RTVE (Spain) is Águila Roja. It is notable among other programmes on their website as all 9 series are available and is good viewing for adults and children alike. Generally, RTVE is good for learning spanish because a full transcript is available along with the programme.

Answer (score 11):

## Mobile apps

All of them are free.

| App | versions | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *Diccionario de la lengua española* by RAE and ASALE | - [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=es.rae.dle) - [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dle/id1011116985?l=es) |  |
| [Duolingo](https://www.duolingo.com/) | - [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.duolingo) - [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/app/duolingo-learn-spanish-french-and-more/id570060128) - [Windows Phone](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/duolingo-learn-languages-for-free/9wzdncrcv5xn) | app to help you learn Spanish with game-like lessons |
| [Anki](https://docs.ankidroid.org/) (similar a *Memrise*) |  | se basa en tarjetas que contienen una palabra/expresión/oración en un idioma y su traducción a otro idioma. La frecuencia con la que te sale cada tarjeta depende de tu facilidad para memorizarla, que tú seleccionas una vez destapas la tarjeta. De esta manera practicas las palabras que te cuestan más. Para saber más, consulta [esta respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/28026/5481). |
| [Speed Spanish](https://speedspanish.co.uk) | - [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.uk.SpeedSpanish) | app with multiple tools and games to help user's learn Spanish, including: Dictionary, translator, conjugator, lessons & multiplayer games. Developed by [Kes Walker](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/25007/kes-walker?tab=profile) |

Comment: Highly recommend Anki, it is one of my favorite flashcard apps.

Answer (score 10):

## Podcasts

- [Radio Ambulante](http://radioambulante.org/) - 2014 winner of the Gabriel García Márquez Prize for Innovation in Journalism.  Distributed by National Public Radio (US), tells Latin American stories through audio, but the site includes transcripts and translations.
- [A la aventura](http://alaaventura.net/) - High quality audio.  The podcasts are categorized as Classics, Science Fiction, Fantasy, Horror, Humor, Young Readers, Nonfiction, Romance, Theater, or Thriller.  Lisa has written about it [here](https://www.duolingo.com/comment/17548839/Latin-American-Spanish-podcasts$comment_id=26716409).
- [Duolingo Spanish Podcasts](https://player.fm/series/duolingo-spanish-podcast) - True stories for English speakers learning Spanish. Fascinating real-life stories in easy-to-understand Spanish with English narration. These are not language lessons; they’re life lessons through language.

---

**Teaching Podcasts**

- [Notes in Spanish](https://www.notesinspanish.com/) - Free podcasts by a Madrileñan and Englishman at Beginner, Intermediate and Advanced levels.  Site has many other features, e.g. links to [videos](https://www.notesinspanish.com/category/videoblogging/), [reports](https://www.notesinspanish.com/2011/01/26/notes-in-spanish-special-reports/), and [books](https://www.notesinspanish.com/notes-in-spanish-books/).  Note, [Beginner level](https://www.notesinspanish.com/category/beginners-podcast/) valuable for Intermediate students also.
- [Coffee Break Spanish](https://radiolingua.com/coffeebreakspanish/) - Part of the Radio Lingua Network which produces a number of different podcasts.  A list of them is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_Lingua_Network#Spanish).  You can also buy lessons, the first of which is free.
- [LightSpeed Spanish](https://lightspeedspanish.co.uk/spanish-lesson-table-contents/) - Four levels (Beginners, Early Intermediate, Advanced Intermediate, and Advanced).  Viewers also have the option of watching a YouTube video instead. (They're the same as the podcast for the most part.)
- [Doorway to Mexico](https://doorwaytomexico.com/episodes/) - The first one is free.  After that, $49 to listen to other podcasts in the collection.   The site also offers a breakdown of the vocabulary and bonus content.  Plus, it prides itself on exposing you to the "real" way people speak (even if it may not be grammatically correct).  Lisa's additional comments may be found [here](https://www.duolingo.com/comment/17548839/Latin-American-Spanish-podcasts$comment_id=26716515).
- [List of 23 different Spanish podcasts](https://podpedia.miraheze.org/wiki/List_of_language_learning_podcasts#Spanish) - includes, for example, ["Accelerated Spanish,"](http://masterofmemory.com/spanish-fluency-day-1/) by Timothy Moser, who claims that his list of six words will give you 10% coverage of the language. (His style and approach might not appeal to everyone.)

Comment: I notice that your code is a bit different than what I've previously been using -- [title](url).  You use the brackets and then add another set of brackets with a numeral and then add a link at the bottom.  I was going to do the same thing, but I kind of see this as a work in progress that's probably still very much in its nascent stages.  Doesn't it complicate the process by adding numbering so early on?  I'm not trying to be rude.  I'm just genuinely curious.

Comment: Some time ago, in a related question, somebody listed few interesting podcasts. See them in [Free online resources for beginner course](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/1196/1674) and feel free to add those you think are good enough :)

Comment: @walen  Very interesting.  So it would seem that this is then a choice of some convenience rather than a coding protocol that programmers try to adhere to.  Let's say it's just easier for a person to do the bracket+parentheses combo.  Will there be any problems in a post that contains mixed coding methods?

Comment: @fedorqui  Thank you for the link.  I'll definitely take a look at it.  And thanks for adding a section on podcasts.  This is a really great resource that I think is sometimes underutilized by beginning learners of Spanish and it's something that could really improve their oral comprehension skills, one of the hardest things to develop while learning a foreign language.

Comment: @LisaBeck - Thanks for the additions.  To match with the style of the rest of this page I'm doing some trimming.  If there's something you feel needs to be restored, though, please do.

Comment: @LisaBeck - You're free to mix and match as walen said; most people usually use the method you used in comments (where the other method doesn't work), and the the highlight-and-click method in posts.  When I'm editing my own or someone else's post, I find it slightly easier to read when the highlight-and-click method was used.

Comment: @aparente  Wow.  I can see evidence of your trimming.  No hard feelings.  It looks much more balanced now.  Well done.

Comment: @LisaBeck - Please double-check my edits to your most recent contribution ("Notes in Spanish" podcast).

Comment: Lisa, I visited the duolingo link you provided under "Door to Mexico" and read your profile there.  I hope you'll include some of that in your SE profile.

Comment: @aparente  That's a really good idea.  Thanks for suggesting it!

Comment: @aparente001  BTW, I like your edits.  They clearly tend to lose a lot of my "voice" and style, but you are very, very good at capturing the essence of what I want others to know, so I don't mind at all.  Well done.  Have you edited professionally in the past?

Comment: @LisaBeck - (cough) Yes.  Also written translations. I was trying for a more succinct presentation; glad you don't mind. // I removed the line before the last entry.  If you want to keep it and make a new section, I suggest you insert a section heading. // How about, from here on out, whenever I edit your post, it will go without saying that my edit is just a suggestion, and please go ahead and roll it back if the edit doesn't feel right?

Comment: @aparente001  Yeah, that's fine about removing the line before the last entry because I've begun sampling that list, and thus far, they seem to be of the "teaching" variety.  Initially, I was thinking that it could be an area where people could add Spanish podcast lists made by others, of which there appears to be quite a few.  But since I haven't determined whether or not any of these "listicles" are worthy for inclusion here and a single item hardly drives a need for a separate category, no real need for a line of separation.  I like your thoughts on editing ...

Comment: @aparente001  ... My style is probably better suited for a blog article rather than a listicle or resource page, so I understand the effect you're going for.  Nevertheless, I'm tempted to give you a nickname.  The first one that comes to mind is The _The Trimmer._

Comment: @aparente001  What professional editing gigs have you had?  You're not a former _Rolling Stones_ editor, are you?

Comment: @LisaBeck - Ha ha, no.  I did a lot of legal writing when I filed for due process for my son who has Tourette Syndrome (we won on appeal) and I've done a wide variety of translations.  Also I did some editing of social sciences journal articles (purely English) -- but that took some extra effort because I have no training in the social sciences. // Would you like to tell me something about yourself?  (Optional -- you decide.)

Answer (score 9):

## Thesauri

- [Sinónimos.com](http://www.sinonimos.com) - Web page specialized in synonyms.
- [Diccionario de sinónimos y antónimos, by WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/sinonimos/) - A section in WordReference dedicated to Spanish synonyms.

Answer (score 8):

## Netflix

#### Spain

- [Películas y programas de TV de España](https://www.netflix.com/browse/genre/107569)

#### Latinamerica

- [Películas y programas de TV latinoamericanos](https://www.netflix.com/browse/genre/100387)

  - [Películas y programas de TV de Chile](https://www.netflix.com/browse/genre/1305303)
  - [Películas y programas de TV de Perú](https://www.netflix.com/browse/genre/2219596)
  - [Películas y programas de TV de Argentina](https://www.netflix.com/browse/genre/100370)
  - [Películas y programas de TV de Colombia](https://www.netflix.com/browse/genre/108229)
  - [Películas](https://www.netflix.com/browse/genre/7825) y [programas de TV](https://www.netflix.com/browse/genre/67644) de México

#### Spanish audio

- [TV en español](https://www.netflix.com/browse/genre/67675)
- [Audio en español](https://www.netflix.com/search?q=spanish&suggestionId=1400072_merch)
- [Subtítulos en español](https://www.netflix.com/search?q=spanish&suggestionId=1300072_merch)
- [Audio en español de España](https://www.netflix.com/search?q=spain&suggestionId=1400080_merch)
- [Audio description in Spanish (Spain)](https://www.netflix.com/search?q=spain&suggestionId=1500080_merch)

---

<sup>**Note:** Some collections may include English language Spain/LATAM made films.</sup>

Answer (score 6):

#### How to learn Spanish

- https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com: a question and answer site within the StackExchange family, intended "for students, teachers, polyglots, and anyone interested in the techniques of second-language acquisition."
- the growing body of Q&As here at Spanish Language!  You can search by a tag you're interested in, such as [subjunctive](/questions/tagged/subjunctive).

Answer (score 6):

## Lists of words

Links to files containing lists of Spanish words, to use in applications or whatever:

- [List with around 80K Spanish words](https://github.com/javierarce/palabras/blob/master/listado-general.txt), excluding variations of number, genre and verb conjugation (i.e. "famoso" is included, but not "famosa", "famosos" or "famosas")
- [Spanish Frequency Lists Compiled at Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Frequency_lists#Spanish) - almost 20 different lists here.  Includes a list of the 2,000 most frequent Spanish nouns.
- [500 Most Common Verbs](http://www.englishnspanish.com/learn/verbs) - Each verb links to a WordReference entry.  Site includes 25 different quizzes.
- [50 most difficult Spanish words to pronounce](http://www.language-pro.info/most-difficult-spanish-words-to-pronounce/) - Pair this with a [Memrise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memrise) course of your own design and some audio recordings from [Forvo](https://forvo.com/languages/es/) and you'll master these in no time.
- [EsPal](http://www.bcbl.eu/databases/espal/) - Online corpus of Spanish words with associated word-properties. You can search for words with given properties, or upload a list of words and return their properties. Results can be downloaded as .txt (maximum 10,000 results per search).

Answer (score 6):

### Other reference resources

- [Spanish Grammar online](http://www.rae.es/recursos/gramatica/nueva-gramatica).
- [Spanish Orthography online](http://www.rae.es/recursos/ortografia/ortografia-2010).

  - When searching both in the Grammar and the Orthography you will see two icons preceding each result. The camera icon will display the whole book page that contains the result, and the magnifier glass icon will display a brief excerpt of that page.
    [image: Search results example]
- [Diccionario de Dudas y Dificultades de la Lengua Española](https://es.scribd.com/doc/151700987/RAE-Seco-Manuel-Diccionario-de-dudas-y-dificultades-de-la-lengua-espanola), from Manuel Seco.
- [Refranero multilingüe](http://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/refranero/Busqueda.aspx), from Centro Virtual Cervantes.

  - Con un completo [listado de todas las paremias en español](https://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/refranero/listado.aspx)
- [InterActive Terminology for Europe (IATE)](http://iate.europa.eu): European Union terminology.
- [Wikilengua del español](http://www.wikilengua.org). (sometimes *la Fundéu* links to this resource as a way to get more information about a term).
- [Diccionario Popular Uruguayo](http://diccionariouruguayo.blogspot.com/) (a blog with vocabulary specific to Uruguay)

Comment: https://www.scribd.com/doc/151700987/RAE-Seco-Manuel-Diccionario-de-dudas-y-dificultades-de-la-lengua-espanola has had the PDF taken down due to a copyright claim.

Answer (score 6):

## Websites

- [*Duolingo*](https://www.duolingo.com/course/es/en/Learn-Spanish-Online) is a website (as well as an app for both Android and iOS) that allows you to learn Spanish (and many other languages) in just 5 minutes a day with game-like lessons.
- [elcastellano.org](http://www.elcastellano.org/) is a website about the Spanish language in general.
- [NachoTime](http://itsnachotime.com) is a website for students trying to get out of Spanish Intermediate Purgatory (maintained by [nachocab](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/users/13617/nachocab)).
- [Memrise](http://www.memrise.com/courses/english/spanish-spain/) is a website (as well as an app for both Android and iOS) for Spanish learners. You can learn Spanish (and many other languages) by using flashcards.
- [Quizlet](https://quizlet.com/) is a website where you can make study sets (or find study sets created by other users) of Spanish (or anything) terms. Quizlet offers several games where you can compete against users across the internet. It also has a flash card mode and a test mode.
- [Destinos](https://www.learner.org/series/destinos/index.html).  An audiovisual course that exposes students to conversations in Spanish, while following a story line.

- [Anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net/). Free, spaced repetition system. It comes in a desktop version and mobile versions. Once you download it you can get free [decks](https://ankiweb.net/shared/decks/spanish) of the most common words or useful sentences.

- [Castellano Actual](http://udep.edu.pe/castellanoactual/) is a blog with articles and answers about the Spanish language and especially the Peruvian dialect.
- [Prutzkow](http://prutzkow.com/en-us/numbers/) - Online number translator into English, Spanish, German, Russian, Finnish.
- [Word of The Hour](https://wordofthehour.org/) - A website that features one basic vocabulary word every hour along with crowd-sourced Spanish language translations.  Translations are crowd-sourced by community members on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Vocabulario/).
- [Spanish Academy](https://spanishacademy.net) - Website with lessons online for beginners. The website also offer 1-on-1 classes with native spanish teachers.

Comment: Technically, a lot of what is on here could be considered a website of some sort.  What about changing the title of this section to "Language Learning Platforms," keeping Duolingo on it, but then also adding sites that also fall into this category?  There's probably even enough of the type that would be considered interactive language learning platforms with some amount of "gaming aspect" or point system to them.  Span¡shD!ct comes to mind, but there's likely to be many others.  Gamified or not, there's Babbel, LingQ, Lingualia, Digital Dialects, et cetera.

Comment: Then you've got sites that are geared more toward conversation (e.g., Conversation Exchange, Hellolingo), and others that are good for getting help with writing practice (e.g., The Mixxer).  Many sites offer multiple features.  For example, Conversation Exchange is mainly for helping people text via chat or make arrangements to chat via voice, but its mail message features make it great for writing corrections (bolding, italicizing, changing colors, ...).

Comment: I suppose a separate category could be created for those and/or some sort of matrix with various features (e.g., chat/conversation, grammar, teachers, free, gamified, et cetera) could be created.  Sites like Memrise, Quizlet, and Anki probably deserve their own separate section since these have one thing in common -- they're flashcard sites.  Destinos (and Extra) along with others of this type also probably deserve a category of their own.  elcastellano.org seems to defy description, so it might be a good choice for a "Multiple Features" category.

Comment: NachoTime is basically a blog, which would also make for a good category because there's a lot of blogs on the Spanish language out there.  I don't recommend making categories for beginning, intermediate, and advanced because those definitions are somewhat nebulous, shifting, and not always apparent or applicable, but if you know for a fact that a site is geared more toward a particular level, subdivisions within the larger main categories or even just annotated and then sorted within categories as such might be useful to those who come to this page.

Comment: @LisaBeck - The beauty of SE is that you can propose a reworking by editing, but it can be rolled back.  If you still feel doubtful, though, why not post a draft reworking at Meta?

Comment: Can I recommend LingQ be added to this section? www.lingq.com it has flashcard, chat, tutoring, free (up to a certain number of flashcards a day,) and gamified features. Users can also import content into a reader that displays translation options from several sources. They also have a library of audiobooks, podcasts, news articles, and free lessons that is organized roughly by level. It's the best language learning website I've ever encountered by far.

Comment: Highly recommend Anki, I used it for Japanese as well.

Answer (score 4):

## Corpora

| Document | Author | Dates | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [**Corpes XXI**](http://web.frl.es/CORPES/view/inicioExterno.view) | RAE | 2001 → 2012 | A corpus of the written Spanish. |
| CREA [**Corpus de Referencia del Español Actual**](http://corpus.rae.es/creanet.html) | RAE | 1975 → 2004 | A corpus of the written Spanish. |
| CORDE [**Corpus Diacrónico del Español**](http://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html) | RAE | its beginnings → 1974 | A corpus of the written Spanish. |
| CNDHE [**Corpus del Nuevo Diccionario Histórico del Español**](http://web.frl.es/CNDHE) | RAE | 12th century → today | The corpus used for building the NDHE, 400 million entries. Allows searching for terms that frequently appear together. |
| [**Hemeroteca Digital de la Biblioteca Nacional de España**](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/) | Biblioteca Nacional de España | 1683 → today | Most of the publications are free to use although many of the most recent ones can only be seen from the library facilities due to copyright restrictions. The texts are completely OCR-scanned and are searchable through its search engine. |

Answer (score 2):

### Videos

Videos from [YouTube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube), [Vimeo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vimeo), and elsewhere will be found in this section.  This post will contain general interest videos or videos that would fall under the category of entertainment — not feature length films (see the Film section for that), television series (see the Television category for that), documentaries, or what would be considered educational programming (see the Documentaries/Educational Programming category for these last two types).

Answer (score 1):

## Dictionaries (paper)

- ***Diccionario de uso del español***. María Moliner. Available in online book stores <sup><sub>(*ahem* Am *ahem* azon *ahem*)</sub></sup> in both book and DVD formats.

Answer (score 1):

### Writing

If you want to practice your Spanish writing you could do so on [r/WriteStreakES](https://www.reddit.com/r/WriteStreakES/)

WriteStreakES is a community where you can write a short text every day and native speakers will correct it for you and tell you what is wrong and why. You can choose your own topic or you can write about fun topics proposed by the moderators every day.

In the same way there is [r/SpeakStreakES](https://www.reddit.com/r/SpeakStreakES/) where you record an audio daily and native speakers will correct you.
*(Note to moderators: if this falls into another category please feel free to delete it and move it there. I didn't see where to put it)*

Answer (score 0):

### Courses

| Course | level | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [FSI Spanish Basic Course](https://www.fsi-language-courses.org/fsi-spanish-basic-course/) | Starter to high level | *It consists of four volumes comprising a total of 60 lessons that include hundreds of drills, speaking exercises, texts for reading practice, and many hours of audio recordings for perfecting your pronunciation.* |