# Books like active reading series for Spanish

Tags: españa

I had 5 different level of active reading books for English which increased my reading very well.
For increasing my reading talent in Spanish:

> **Is there any book(or series of books) for Spanish? like active reading? to teach us how to read faster.**

For more information about active reading series plz visit: [ngl cengage](http://ngl.cengage.com/)

- I'm not talking about an online website for it like:
  [wattpad](http://www.wattpad.com/home) or something like this!
- I just need books for reading when i'm not online.

I asked this question on duolingo.com, but nobody answered.

Comment: See [Resources for learning Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23617/5481). Questions asking for resources for learning Spanish are off-topic, since they are primarily opinion based. We created that community wiki post so people could contribute resources for learning Spanish to help other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i don't know your actual level of Spanish, but if you are a beginner you can read books like "***The Wonderful Wizard of Oz***" who is called "***El maravilloso mago de Oz***" in Spanish, so if you don't understand some word or expression you can check it on the original book's language.

I you want to go further you can start with books like this. 
This can be a good one to start and it is free online [***El Alquimista***](http://www.formarse.com.ar/libros/Libros-recomendados-pdf/El%20Alquimista-Paulo%20Coelho.pdf)

There is a serie of books that uses stylishly Spanish language, "***El cementerio de los Libros Olvidados***", that starts with the book ["***La Sombra del Viento***"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_sombra_del_viento) ,I would recommend it too.

If you like Poe you can go with Poe's Tales, you can find them free online and they are well translated in Spanish. Or if you want something new you can read the famous peruvian poet [***César Vallejo***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A9sar_Vallejo)

When you'd be an expert you can go to books like Game of Thrones.

Hope it helps you :D

Comment: i'm not beginner and i'm also not a pro! ... My lvl is: learned about 3k word in spanish.

Comment: Wow haha, well if my answer doesn't help you, i can add some books more :)

Comment: ok, that's enough dude:) i'll try to read them, thanks anyway... and if no one has a better answer than yours till 2h... i ll accept your answer:)

Comment: Ok :) Just a suggest: if you want better recommendations, you can specify what kind of books do you like.

Comment: any kind of books that i can improve my reading skills...

Comment: I found La Sombra del Viento pretty hard going, and wouldn't recommend it as a first novel. I recommend starting with kids' books, especially ones that were originally written in English as they often have a more familiar sentence structures to an English speaker. My suggestions would be Harry Potter, or one of Isabel Allende's children's books.