# Is there any idiom in Spanish for 'great minds think alike'?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-modismo

[*Great minds think alike*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/295446/37429) is a humorous expression to use when you find someone else doing or thinking the same exact thing you were.

I like it very much, because it is funny and also kind of flattering to the person you are talking to.

Imagine you are in your work and you propose picking up a screwdriver to mend the coffee machine. At the same exact moment, somebody appears with that. Ha! You say *great minds think alike*.

I wonder if Spanish has any similar idiom. ***Los genios pensamos igual*** is the direct translation, but does not sound that well.

Comment: En Colombia decimos "Dios los cría, ellos se juntan" que es similar también a la otra frase "birds of a feather flock together"

Comment: De cuenta de esta pregunta acabo de encontrar un recurso interesante. Se llama **Refranero multilingue** del Centro Virtual Cervantes. No contiene la respuesta para esta pregunta, pero puede dar origen a muchas más. :-) la [pag inicial](https://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/refranero/Default.aspx) 
 y el  [listado](https://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/refranero/listado.aspx)

Comment: Lamentablemente no tengo gran repertorio de refranes y dichos.  Estoy de acuerdo que lo literal no suena bien.  Ojalá y haya algo como *Por diferentes caminos, los astutos llegan a la misma idea.*

Comment: @aparente001 oye pues la que propones no la había oído nunca pero suena bien.

Comment: @DGaleano pues no lo conocía, pero veo que algún miembro de la comunidad [ya sí](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/24312/1674). Es una joya, añadí un subitem con el listado completo. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole english saying is "Great minds think alike, but fools seldom differ". You could translate this as "Las grandes mentes piensan igual. Y los tontos rara vez difieren".

There are tons of pages in spanish referring to this english proverb. For example [here](http://blogs.elpais.es/elenigma/2006/08/grandes_mentes_.html)