# ¿Existe alguna raíz que produzca verbos válidos para las tres terminaciones?

Tags: verbos, solicitud-de-término

Jugando un poco con el diccionario, veo que hay algunas raíces que producen verbos para dos terminaciones:

- [Temar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZOl6PnN) / [temer](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZPXY3qZ).
- [Tejar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZKUCmXp) / [tejer](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZKibnfG).
- [Cerner](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8M0MAxV) / [cernir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8ML9BHk).
- [Surcar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YnCnvLH) / [Surcir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YnEsofm) (varía la pronunciación pero me valdría).
- [Segar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XRxDOOj) / [Seguir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XT8l8aE) (misma pronunciación y distinta escritura, también me valdría).

Pero de momento no he conseguido dar con ninguna raíz que produzca los verbos correspondientes a cada una de las tres terminaciones posibles. ¿Existe tal raíz?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

¡Hay una!

- **[*rendar*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VwiNfiQ) / [*render*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VwkynFY) / [*rendir*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Vx2mt0Q)**

En [List of words](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/24298/1674) tenemos un enlace a una [lista de unas 80 mil palabras](https://github.com/javierarce/palabras/blob/master/listado-general.txt) y haciendo algo de *scripting** obtuve ese resultado.

Encuentro algunas otras combinaciones interesantes:

- [*compeler*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=A0FWz6W) / [*compelir*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=A0HLxdJ) (son sinónimas)
- [*competer*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=A0o8FgX) / [*competir*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=A0rP4Nu) (la 1.ª tiene una acepción sinónima, pero en desuso, de la 2.ª)
- [*interromper*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Lx0PEQl) / [*interrumpir*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Lx11HLa) (son sinónimas)

---

*Cogí la lista y extraje solamente las que terminan en "r". Ese fichero lo procesé con Python:

```
def lee():
    """Lee el fichero y guarda las raíces en conjuntos, 
    para poder buscar después coincidencias."""

    lineas = []
    bloques = {
        'ar': set(),
        'er': set(),
        'ir': set()
    }

    with open('verbos.txt', 'r') as f:
        for linea in f:
            linea = linea.rstrip()
            lineas.append(linea)
            terminacion = linea[-2:]  # coge la terminación
            stem = linea[:-2]  # coge la raíz de la palabra
            bloques[terminacion].add(stem)

    return lineas, bloques

def busca_majas(ar, er, ir):
    """Detecta intersecciones entre las raíces."""

    print("ar - er:", ar.intersection(er))
    print("ar - ir:", ar.intersection(ir))
    print("er - ir:", er.intersection(ir))
    print("total:", ar.intersection(er).intersection(ir))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lineas, bloques = lee()
    ar = bloques['ar']
    er = bloques['er']
    ir = bloques['ir']
    busca_majas(ar, er, ir)
```

Si se guarda este script en un fichero `algocharlie.py`, se puede ejecutar con:

```
grep -E '(ar|er|ir)$' lista_palabras.txt > verbos.txt
python algocharlie.py
```

Comment: Mola, la segunda pregunta que hago en el sitio que se resuelve con un algoritmo... :-D

Comment: ¿Qué me dices del caso de que la raíz se base en el sonido de la palabra? Ejemplo inventado: me podría servir "danzar", "dancer" y "dancir". Por motivos ortográficos la "z" se transformaría en "c" en las otras terminaciones. Lo mismo con verbos que acaben en "gar", "guer", "guir" (¿existen de estos dos últimos?), o en "jar", "ger/jer" "gir/jir".

Answer (score 2):

## [rendar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VwiNfiQ), [render](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VwkynFY), [rendir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Vx2mt0Q)

(rendir y render son sinónimos)

---

Código de SQL ( <sup>tiempo de ejecución: 11028ms</sup> ):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT word FROM verbs WHERE WORD LIKE "%er") AS x
JOIN
(SELECT word FROM verbs WHERE WORD LIKE "%ar") AS y
JOIN 
(SELECT word FROM verbs WHERE WORD LIKE "%ir") AS z

ON  SUBSTR(x.word, 1,LENGTH(x.word)-2) = SUBSTR(y.word, 1,LENGTH(y.word)-2)
AND SUBSTR(x.word, 1,LENGTH(x.word)-2) = SUBSTR(z.word, 1,LENGTH(z.word)-2)
```

Comment: ¡Gracias, ukemi! Lástima que fedorqui encontrara esta misma respuesta cinco minutos antes que tú, así que le di a él la marca de respuesta correcta.

Comment: Ah, demasiado lento esta vez... haha

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿con qué base de datos trabajas?

Comment: @fedorqui http://www.bcbl.eu/databases/espal/

Comment: Tremendo recurso, no lo conocía ukemi. No consigo enterar en la zona de ejecutar código SQL. ¿Te apetece añadir el recurso en [Resources for learning Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23617/1674) con una pequeñísima guía de uso?

Comment: Ah, no hay tal zona en el sitio web. Descargué sus listas de lemas como archivos .txt hace un tiempo y creé una base de datos en mi propio ordenador.