# ¿Es correcta la frase "breves instantes que se subsiguieron al..."?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, sintaxis, verbo-pronominal

¿Alguna de estas frases es correcta?

- breves instantes que se subsiguieron al...
- breves instantes que se le subsiguieron al...
- breves instantes que le subsiguieron al...

o bien ninguna es correcta. Casi no encuentro ejemplos del uso de "subsiguieron" en internet.

Quiero formar la frase:

> el escuadrón veintidós dejó de existir en los breves instantes que se subsiguieron al apagón

Estoy al tanto de lo rebuscado que puede sonar.

Comment: Parece extremadamente rebuscado. ¿Cuál es el contexto?

Comment: @pablodf76 Quiero formar la frase "el escuadrón veintidós dejó de existir en los breves instantes que se subsiguieron al apagón", estoy al tanto de lo rebuscado que puede sonar.

Comment: Creo que no es reflexivo.  Creo que seria mejor: "en los breves instantes que subsiguieron al apagón".

Comment: Chequee con google y encontre un libro, Las grandes revoluciones jurídicas y el problema social, que tiene "en los momentos caóticos, para la sociedad europea, que subsiguieron al ...."

Answer (score 1):

El verbo [*subseguir*](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=YZP2zZM) está registrado en el DLE:

> 1. intr. Dicho de una cosa: Seguir inmediatamente a otra. U. t. c. prnl.

Sin embargo, su uso es marginal y añade un innecesario nivel de complicación a lo que quieres decir. Por ejemplo, si buscamos en el [CORDE](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/24314/1674) vemos apenas 14 usos de la palabra *subseguir*, tal cual, en los últimos siglos. La única entrada de este siglo menciona algo así como *... importante para el diagnóstico. La colangitis puede subseguir a la obstrucción del colédoco, en cuyo caso...* Esto es, pertenece a un lenguaje harto técnico. En el CREA no encuentro nada y en el Corpes (desde 2001) dos entradas, de textos de Argentina (texto historico) y Venezuela (texto médico).

Por tanto, y en pos de la claridad, yo diría algo tan simple como:

> el escuadrón veintidós dejó de existir en los breves instantes que  **siguieron** al apagón.

Comment: ¿Alguna explicación del voto negativo?