# Manual on the Spanish language

Tags: recursos

I'm interested in a documentation on the Spanish language. Like really concise - similar to the documentation of a computer language.

There's a lot of bloat on learning languages online or sometimes even in textbooks.

If you could show me some very concise or to the point resource on technical aspects of understanding the language that would help me (and make me very happy).

Comment: Do any of the resources listed https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23617/resources-for-learning-spanish-recursos-para-aprender-espa%C3%B1ol help?

Comment: A formal language is a lot different from a natural language. Actually we call them "languages" but they're really not that similar. Take a look at the available resources and maybe you can find some that deal with specific parts of Spanish in a concise, formal-grammar-like manner. You won't find that kind of material *for the whole language*.

Comment: mdewey Yes this will help a bit, thanks. @pablodf76 OK thanks for the clarification, it will help.

Comment: I marked the question as duplicate of the one indicated by @mdewey. Check it out, whitevinyl, and let us know if it fits all your needs. Otherwise, [edit] again and clarify a bit further what exactly you are looking for. Thanks for passing by!