# Frequency list for morphemes

Tags: etimología, sufijos, recursos, prefijos

Being a native speaker of English, and having a reasonably large English-language vocabulary, especially for words of Latin origin, and having studied Latin in high school, I tend to be reasonably good at being able to guess the meaning of Spanish words I haven't seen before. However, I tend to struggle a bit with morphemes, such as [-ción](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ci%C3%B3n).

Are there any frequency lists which list morphemes by how frequently they are used, with examples of their usage?

I tried looking at the tag [sufijos](/questions/tagged/sufijos) and [prefijos](/questions/tagged/prefijos) and searched for "morfema" and "morpheme" on this site, and also searched the page [Resources for learning Spanish / Recursos para aprender español](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23617/resources-for-learning-spanish-recursos-para-aprender-espa%C3%B1ol) for any mention of morphemes.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a great list of Spanish morphemes in this document full of examples.
Frequency of use is not mentioned but I think it would be useful.

The link belongs to the high school I.E.S.Séneca, in Córdoba, Spain. No author is explicitly mentioned.

http://www.iesseneca.net/iesseneca/IMG/pdf/PREFIJOS_SUFIJOS_E_INTERFIJOS.pdf

Comment: Sería bueno que compartieras algún detalle del documento, para que si deja de funcionar el enlace tu respuesta siga teniendo utilidad

Comment: @fedorqui Lo he pensado, pero no sabría resumirlo, son muchas tablas de morfemas y ejemplos. ¿Qué morfemas copio?

Comment: @fedorqui También había pensado dejarlo como comentario pero no estaba seguro.

Comment: Es que de hecho el OP pregunta por cantidades, mientras que este documento ofrece una lista bastante pormenorizada, pero sin indicar cuánto se usan. No sé hasta qué punto es útil para el OP, vaya :) Dicho lo cual, ofrece info muy jugosa que seguro que en otras preguntas del sitio sería muy útil

Comment: @fedorqui Correcto, no ofrece frecuencia de uso y así lo he indicado. A ver qué dice Andrew.