# audio readings of Spanish poetry

Tags: literatura

I am a mathematician (johnbcosgrave.com). Earlier this year I started to study Spanish through Future Learn (futurelearn.com). I want to obtain audio recordings of Spanish authors (e.g. Antonio Muñoz Molina, whose 'La noche de los tiempos' I have read in English translation) or poets (e.g., Pablo Neruda, whose 'Veinte Poemas de Amor y una Canción Desesperada' - with his reading on CD - I bought in Valencia last month). I have tried internet searches, but with little success. I would very much appreciate any pointers. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hello, John, and welcome! Please check this list of [resources for learning Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23617/12637) to see if you find anything of interest. Feel free to add there any other resources you consider of value.

Comment: Hello John, welcome to [spanish.se]. We suggest you check the [tour] and [help] pages and have a look at other questions and answers to fully understand how this site works. I'm sorry to have closed your question (I understand it's rather unwelcoming for a new user) but asking for learning resources is not [on topic](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Charlie. Many thanks for the links you gave me. John

Diego. It's okay that you 'closed' my question. John