# ¿Hay recursos buenos para ampliar el vocabulario español avanzado?

Tags: vocabulario, recursos

He llegado a un punto donde domino bastante bien el castellano, pero quiero aumentar mi vocabulario avanzado.  Sé perfectamente que la mejor manera hacerlo es leer y buscar las palabras no conocidas en un diccionario.  Pero me gustaría algo más sistemático: una app, una página web, etc, que me oblique a aprender las palabras.  Estoy buscando recursos para un vocabulario de nivel avanzado -- hay muchas apps, por ejemplo, para un vocabulario de nivel básico, pero no he encontrado nada para el nivel avanzado.  Hace algún tiempo tuve una app de MemWords que era bastante bien, pero está diseñada para el iPhone, que no tengo ahora. Si hay un libro bueno que permita ampliar mi vocabulario está bien, pero no he tenido mucho éxito con libros de vocabulario, ya que consisten, más o menos, en listas que deben memorizarse: es una idea buena pero que resulta, al fin y al cabo, un poco aburrido, por tanto estoy buscando algo más "dinámico".  Gracias por cualquier sugerencia!

Comment: see https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23617/resources-for-learning-spanish-recursos-para-aprender-espa%c3%b1ol?r=SearchResults&s=3|32.1383

Comment: Dado que este tipo de preguntas puede tener muchas posibles respuestas igualmente válidas, la comunidad ha decidido considerarlas _off topic_. Para ayudar a los usuarios a localizar y compartir recursos, hemos creado la pregunta canónica [resources for learning Spanish / Recursos para aprender español](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23617/5481)

Comment: @Diego -- Entiendo lo que dices, y sabía que mi pregunta puede ser considera "off topic", pero al fin y al cabo, no estoy de acuerdo.  Desde una respuesta a mi pregunta, la de David Albandea, me enteré de la app AnkiDroid, la cual, en combinación con una lista de vocabulario avanzado, es exactamente lo que buscaba.  No veo esta app en el enlace arriba -- aunque ahí hay muchas cosas buenas.  Creo que debe haber más flexibilidad con preguntas como la mía, porque tales "preguntas canónicas" frecuentemente no se han respondido en las listas generales como "Resources of learning Spanish".

Comment: @Cerulean No es mi opinión personal. Esto ha sido discutido por la comunidad en Meta. Tú y/o cualquier miembro de la comunidad podéis votar para reabrir la pregunta si queréis. Clarificación aparte: no es que tu pregunta no vaya a tener respuestas interesantes, pero, como se dice en [help] deberíamos "avoid asking subjective questions where every answer is equally valid" y como este tipo de pregunta sobre recursos de aprendizaje es muy frecuente la hemos identificado como ["canónica"](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2505/5481) y recogido en la que he enlazado antes.

Comment: Sí, no digo que sea tu opinión personal y no me quejo. Entiendo la finalidad de la decisoon. Solo es que no habria descubierto el recurso que buscaba si no hubiera podido preguntar, ya que este recurso no está en la lista general. Esto me parece problemático. Pero eso es una discusión para 'meta'...

Comment: Me explico: no es que no debieras haber hecho esa pregunta y la cerramos porque no corresponde. La cerramos por un proceso de "indexación" y limpieza. Cierto que tú y todos hemos descubierto un recurso interesante que no estaba listado, pero piensa en quienes usen el stack para buscar recursos similares. Deben hacer una pregunta cada vez? Mirar cada respuesta para preguntas tipo "recomendarme un libro/recurso básico/avanzado/intermedio"? Imagina rebuscar en múltiples preguntas tan similares y con un rango tan amplio que además tienen múltiples respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay una aplicación llamada AnkiDroid que se basa en tarjetas que contienen una palabra/expresión/oración en un idioma y su traducción a otro idioma. La frecuencia con la que te sale cada tarjeta depende de tu facilidad para memorizarla, que tú seleccionas una vez destapas la tarjeta. De esta manera practicas las palabras que te cuestan más.

Hay barajas compartidas (shared decks) online, pero si tu nivel es muy avanzado puede que no encuentres ninguna a tu gusto. Pero puedes hacerte tus propias barajas, y las cartas no tienen por qué contener la traducción a otro idioma si no quieres. Puedes poner la información que quieras.

Por lo tanto, yo te recomiendo que sigas leyendo textos avanzados y que te hagas una baraja con las palabras difíciles que vayas encontrando. Si consigues añadir nuevas cartas y las repasas de manera sistemática, adquirirás mucho vocabulario.

Answer (score 2):

Te sugiero leas publicaciones especializadas, (tales como articulos cientificos, libros universitarios, carteles de ponencias), de preferencia relacionados con tu disciplina o area del conocimiento.

Es muy probable que te consigas muchas palabras nuevas que enriqueceran tu vocabulario.

Buena suerte!