# What's the difference between the various context dictionaries available for Spanish (e.g., Tatoeba, Reverso, Linguee, ...)?

Tags: traducción, recursos, diccionarios

A few years ago I discovered my first online context dictionary — [**Tatoeba**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tatoeba).  Up until then, I had never seen anything quite like it (other than [**Google Translate**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Translate)) and immediately began using it on a regular basis.  Then, about a month later, I discovered [**Reverso**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverso_(language_tools)).  (I think someone had mentioned Reverso in a [**Duolingo**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duolingo) thread.)  I checked it out, and have been hooked ever since.  Since then I've seen others (e.g., [**Linguee**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguee), [**Span¡shD!ct**](https://www.spanishdict.com/translation), ...), but none appeal to me as much as Reverso.

As my Spanish gets better, however, I am getting the impression that not all of Reverso's Spanish translations are the best they could be.  I'm interested in knowing how true bilinguals feel about the translations from these sites and others like them.  Specifically, I'm interested in knowing about ...

- ### ... the quality of the translations and any criteria you use to make that determination
- ### ... the methodology these context dictionaries use.  For example:

  > - **Who (or what) is doing the translating?**
  >
  >   > - Human or machine?
  >   >
  >   >   > - If human, what type of humans and what are their credentials?
  >   >   > - If machine, what type of machine?
  > - **Are the translations a mix of English to Spanish and vice versa or are they just from Spanish into English or English into Spanish?**
  > - **Where do the translations come from (e.g., film/tv, books, newspapers, ...)?**
- ### ... why you prefer one over another
- ### ... how they compare to Google Translate

If you are not a true bilingual, but you have some experience with a Spanish context dictionary or know how they operate, I wholeheartedly welcome any comment you wish to make or answer you'd like to provide.

---

**¿Cuál es la diferencia entre los diversos diccionarios de contexto disponibles para el español (por ejemplo, Tatoeba, Reverso, Linguee, ...)?**

Hace unos años descubrí mi primer diccionario de contexto en línea: [**Tatoeba**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tatoeba). Hasta ese momento, nunca había visto nada igual (aparte del [**Traductor de Google**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traductor_de_Google)) e inmediatamente comencé a usarlo regularmente. Luego, alrededor de un mes después, descubrí el [**Reverso**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverso_(language_tools)). Creo que alguien mencionó Reverso en un hilo de [**Duolingo**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duolingo).  Lo comprobé y he estado enganchada desde ese momento. Desde entonces he visto otros (por ejemplo, [**Linguee**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguee), [**Span¡shD!Ct**](https://www.spanishdict.com/translation), ...), pero ninguno me atrae tanto como Reverso.

Sin embargo, a medida que mi español mejora, me da la impresión de que no todas las traducciones al español de Reverso son lo mejor. Me interesa saber cómo se sienten los verdaderos bilingües acerca de las traducciones de estos sitios y otros similares. Específicamente, me interesa saber algo acerca de ...

- ### ... la calidad de las traducciones y los criterios que utilices para hacer esa determinación
- ### ... la metodología que usan estos diccionarios de contexto. Por ejemplo:

  > - **¿Quién (o qué) está haciendo las traducciones?**
  >
  >   > - ¿Ser humano o máquina?
  >   >
  >   >   > - Si es ser humano, ¿qué tipo de ser humano?  Y ¿cuáles son sus credenciales?
  >   >   > - Si es máquina, ¿qué tipo de máquina?
  > - **¿Son las traducciones una mezcla de inglés al español y viceversa?  O, ¿son sólo del español al inglés o del inglés al español?**
  > - **¿De dónde vienen las traducciones (por ejemplo, cine / televisión, libros, periódicos, ...)?**
- ### ... por qué prefieres uno sobre otro
- ### ... cómo se comparan con Google Translate

Aunque no seas completamente bilingüe, pero tienes algo de experiencia con algún diccionario de contexto, o sabes cómo operan, también me interesa recibir tu comentario o respuesta.

Comment: Curioso, "tatoeba" (例えば) es la palabra que se usa en japonés para decir "por ejemplo".

Comment: Relacionado: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23618/12637

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Si no es problema, contestaré en español. Iré uno por uno. Me concentraré en describir cómo funcionan estos sistemas de traducción (incluido Google Translate) y, al final, comentaré cuáles prefiero y por qué.

1. **Linguee**: No es un sistema de traducción, ni un diccionario. Es, mejor dicho, **un buscador web** desarrollado por [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/home), una empresa alemana dedicada a la aplicación de inteligencia artificial en los idiomas. Linguee [busca en páginas bilingües](https://translate.google.com.mx/translate?sl=de&tl=es&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.golem.de%2F0904%2F66396.html) (como sitios web de tiendas, o páginas de la Unión Europea) el término de búsqueda y, con base en esto, ofrece una traducción aproximada del término (que normalmente incluye bastantes variaciones contextuales ordenadas por frecuencia de uso), así como múltiples ejemplos de frases traducidas. El algoritmo es refinado con [retroalimentación humana](https://www.deepl.com/blog/20181205.html) sobre la calidad de la traducción (muy probablemente, por medio de [pruebas ciegas](https://www.deepl.com/blog/20181205.html) donde el humano no sabe el origen de la traducción).
2. **Tatoeba**: Es un diccionario que depende de las [contribuciones voluntarias de personas para conformar una base de datos de frases y palabras](https://tatoeba.org/eng/about) con sus respectivas traducciones. Al igual que Linguee, intenta proporcionar una traducción en distintos contextos.
3. **SpanishDiCt**: Es un diccionario [conformado de las siguientes fuentes](http://Vel%C3%A1zquez%20Spanish%20and%20English%20Dictionary): Un diccionario propio escrito por lexicógrafos bilingües, el C*ollins Complete Spanish Electronic Dictionary* y el *Velázquez Spanish and English Dictionary*. [En cuanto a su servicio de conjugación, lo subarrendan a Onoma,](http://www.onoma.es/conjugador/nosotros.html) un sistema que, por medio de inteligencia artificial, detecta patrones en las conjugaciones de los verbos.
4. **Translate y Reverso**: [Google Translate](https://ai.googleblog.com/2016/09/a-neural-network-for-machine.html) y [Reverso](https://www.corporate-translation.reverso.com/translation-technologies) funcionan, a rasgos generales, de una manera muy similar a Linguee. Sus sistemas depende de sitios web multilingües (en el caso de Reverso, también de bases de datos personalizadas), como sitios de organizaciones multilaterales. Por medio de técnicas de inteligencia artificial (particularmente, redes neuronales), sus sistemas tratan de descifrar la relación que hay entre los componentes de un enunciado en distintos idiomas y, así, **conforman un diccionario** (no técnicamente, pero es útil imaginarlo así). Sus sistemas también dependen de la retroalimentación del usuario. Las técnicas de inteligencia artificial implementadas por Google y Reverso permiten traducir textos más grandes que los otros sistemas.

Personalmente, prefiero **Linguee y SpanishDiCt**. La enorme ventaja que tiene **SpanishDiCt** sobre los demás es que sus **fuentes son controladas y verificables**; son diccionarios publicados por casas editoriales, sabemos cuáles exactamente son, y muy seguramente pasaron por procesos de revisión más rigurosos. Aunque esto puede suponer una limitación (no hay traducción contextualizada, y la incorporación de nuevos usos y palabras es más lenta), hay certeza sobre la calidad del servicio. Le sigue **Linguee** porque me gusta cómo despliega todos los posibles significados de las palabras (derivado de distintos contextos donde es posible usar la palabra). Además, tomando en cuenta lo técnico, a diferencia de otros servicios que usan métodos de inteligencia artificial, Linguee **implementa controlada y sistemáticamente, revisiones sobre la calidad de su traducción que no dependen del usuario**.

Recomendaría **evitar Tatoeba**, pues la principal fuente de información para sus sistema de traducción son **aportaciones de usuarios que no son sistemáticamente verificadas y mejoradas**.

Comment: Muy completa y informativa. Gx por tu tiempo/esfuerzo. Me hizo explorar Linguee un poco más. Entiendo lo que has dicho sobre Linguee, pero aun así, prefiero Reverso pq me da # de traducciones para cada traducción. Me gustan mucho los #s. Más específicamente, a mí me molan las frecuencias. A este respecto, normalmente no me interesa estudiar usos excepcionales de una palabra o frase; me interesa estudiar los más frecuentes o comunes. Reverso me ayuda hacer precisamente eso. En cuanto a la codiciada marca verde de verificación, no voy a otorgarla ahora mismo, pero eres un contendiente fuerte.