# Traducción (alternativa) de "task force"

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico

Por una serie de recientes acontecimientos, me estoy encontrando en varios medios españoles con la expresión "**grupo de combate**" como traducción de ***task force***.

Desconozco si "grupo de combate" es la expresión usada habitualmente en círculos militares, pero creo que hay una diferencia de matiz bastante clara respecto del original:

- ***Task force*** es un conjunto organizado de efectivos militares (*force*: [MW 2b](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/force), [OX 4](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/force)) asignados a una tarea concreta (*task*). Puede ser de combate, de reconocimiento, de maniobras, humanitaria, logística o lo que sea. (De hecho, diría que es probable que un grupo orientado específicamente a combate tenga otra denominación distinta del genérico *task force*.)
- **Grupo de combate** parece reducir bastante el abanico de tareas, refiriéndose exclusivamente a un grupo de efectivos destinado a tareas de combate.

Como digo, puede ser que en terminología militar el significado de "grupo de combate" sea más amplio y equivalente al de *task force* en inglés, o que en inglés lo de *task force* sea un eufemismo; pero en lenguaje llano creo que transmiten imágenes distintas.

**¿Cuál podría ser una traducción de *task force* que transmita mejor el sentido de fuerza militar dedicada a una tarea concreta, pero no necesariamente de combate?**

Comment: La ONU prefiere *equipo de tareas* aunque generalmente creo que bastaría con comisión o comité

Comment: No tengo ni idea de términos militares pero ¿podría ser una opción "unidad táctica"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La página web del IATE (European Union terminology) da las siguientes [traducciones](https://iate.europa.eu/search/standard/result/1557909490976/1):

- grupo operativo
- grupo de acción
- unidad especial
- grupo de estudio
- grupo de trabajo
- comisión especial
- comisión técnica

Estas traducciones tendrían un sentido amplio, no restringido al ámbito militar, y responderían a la siguiente definición:

> Conjunto de personas a las que se encarga de manera temporal el examen de una cuestión concreta y la elaboración de informes o recomendaciones al respecto.

Si nos restringimos al ámbito militar, la web da esta otra opción como traducción:

- fuerza operativa

Esta traducción tiene el siguiente comentario:

> En el contexto de la OTAN, la voz inglesa *task force* (en francés, *force opérationnelle*) tiene tres significados posibles:
>   1) Agrupamiento temporal de unidades, bajo un solo mando, constituido con el propósito de llevar a cabo una operación específica o realizar una misión.
>   2) Organización semipermanente de unidades, bajo un solo mando, constituida con la finalidad de ejecutar una misión específica continuada.
>   3) Componente de la flota, organizado por el mando de la flota operativa o una autoridad superior, para realizar una o varias misiones específicas.

Cualquiera de estas traducciones podría encajar con el significado que comentas de *task force* en inglés, ya elegir una u otra dependería del contexto.

Comment: @walen la web del IATE ya está en la lista de recursos, donde pone [other reference sources](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/24312/12637). De hecho no me acordaba de la dirección de la web y fui a buscarla allí. :-)