# ¿Qué es "tronarse a un mancito"?

Tags: verbos, definiciones, coloquialismos, colombia

I heard the following sentence in the Narcos TV series (which takes place in Colombia):

> Yo fuí el que se **tronó** a ese mancito.

Context: two killers are discussing a guy they have taken out last night.

What does "tronarse" mean in this context? "To kill"? I assume it is Colombian slang, as I cannot find that meaning in the Word Reference dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the official dictionary of the language which in its entry for [tronar](https://dle.rae.es/tronar?m=form) says

> 9. tr. El Salv. y Méx. Matar a tiros. En El Salv., u. t. c. prnl.

Although it does not specify Colombia this seems too much of a coincidence not to be true

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll take a look at the DLE next time. I assume that "tronarse" is a pronominal verb (requires "se") in Colombia as in El Salvador.

Comment: Interestingly, [DAMER's reference to _tronar(se)_](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=CSF8jtu4lx0AhDTplW6) does not include Colombia, while it definitely should have. cc @Alan DAMER (Diccionario de americanismos) is always a good resource for such things.

Comment: @Alan - I think the "se" is there because the meaning is more or less "I myself took him out."  After all, even for a hardened killer, assassinating someone can take a lot out of the assassin. // Have you met our Resources page yet?  It has a great collection of dictionaries.  Also linguee.com is *very* fun -- although not perhaps relevant for *this* question, and not exactly a dictionary.  But there you can see lots of authentic usage examples.  Here's our Resources page: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23617/9385