# ¿Podéis recomendar recursos (online) para practicar los aproximantes de 'b', 'd', 'g'?

Tags: pronunciación

Estoy intentando mejorar mi pronunciación de español. Una cosa que quiero practicar son los sonidos de los aproximantes de 'b' (β), 'g' (ɣ̞) y 'd' (ð̞). Entiendo bastante bien qué son, y la diferencia entre estos y las oclusivas 'normales', pero quisiera escuchar y practicar más. Quizás algo similar a https://soundsofspeech.uiowa.edu/main/spanish pero con más audio y más ejemplos para poder contrastar los sonidos. Me parece que el aproximante de 'g' es especialmente difícil de dominar. ¡Gracias!

Comment: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23617/resources-for-learning-spanish-recursos-para-aprender-espa%c3%b1ol/23623#23623 puede ayudarte.

Comment: @mdewey -- ¡Me parece un colección genial y la voy a mirar!  Aun así, si existen algunos recursos específicamente pensados para el tema de aproximantes, estos me ayudarían.

Comment: Soy hablante nativo de español y es la primera vez que escucho la expresión "aproximantes".

Comment: @alvalongo -- Ve https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonante_aproximante, por ejemplo.  Son para los fonemas 'b','g', y 'd' cuando estos no son oclusivos, es decir, cuando se permite un poco de aire fluir.