# A combo insult in Mexican Spanish

Tags: selección-de-palabras, expresiones, méxico, vulgaridades, insultos

I'm writing a screenplay with a Mexican American character in it.
At one point she becomes extremely annoyed by news from work and launches into a string of insults in her native language to express vexation.
My knowledge of Spanish is beginner-intermediate and I'm stumbling with this part :(
I've tried googling and youtubing, but 99% of results are just separate words. What I am looking for is a rolling tirade of various Mexican swear words, euphemisms and dysphemisms that would be strong and NSFW but inventive and hilarious for native speakers to hear!

So far I've come up with the following *(not sure about the last phrase; sounds more Spain Spanish to me than Mexican)*:

> ¡Hijo de la puta chingadera! ¡Vete a la verga pinche culero! ¡No me
>   salgas con tu pendejadas mamón! ¡Cago en coño de tu puta madre!

Somehow this doesn't sound right...

Would be grateful for any advices or directions :)

**Text that I'm looking for shall:**

- Express general annoyance, not directed at anyone specifically (such as "fuck this shit" in English)
- Contain a few sentences since the character would continue swearing while the screen Fades To Black (with profanities still heard)
- Contain some Mexico-specific words or phrases
- Be strong but funny

**Character description:**

- A *chicana* living in Texas
- Born in Hermosillo, Sonora
- In her mid-thirties
- Educated but currently in the military, so rather rough-edged

Comment: Welcome to our site, Alexander! This seems a really fun question and I hope our Mexican friends will have a great time trying to come up with combo insults or refining what you made up. You can start with the _Diccionario de americanismos_ to see if a given word is actually used in Mexico, as in this [example](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=chingadera). You only need to check that the definition is preceded with the _Mx_ flag.

Comment: yeah, I too applaud the opportunity to hear a fun load of Mexican swearing! (we're all here to learn and have fun!)

Comment: Thanks @Charlie, that's a great resource, I've bookmarked it :)

Comment: You're welcome, you can also check out our [Resources for learning Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23617/12637) question, I'm sure you will find it useful. :-)

Comment: Rest assured, *none of that sounds like Iberian Spanish*. By the way, I suggest you see the series: *La Reina del Sur* or *Falsa Identidad* or *Ingobernable* on Netflix. And there are many others about crime, drugs and politics full of well-delivered nastiness. These series are written by **Mexican** writers. [cago en el x de tu y]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am from Hermosillo, Sonora, and i can give you some tips:

- Speak with the northern Mexican accent, but not like Nuevo Leon accent (which is the most known), the accent from Sonora is loud and short, not lengthening the words.
- Switch the pronuntiation of "Ch" to "Sh", make words like "Chingado" sound like "Shingado".
- Use local words in the mix, like "Bishi" meaning "Naked". This can help: https://matadornetwork.com/es/15-terminos-imprescindibles-para-entender-el-espanol-sonorense/
- Never use "pinche", use "pinchi" instead.
- And the most important, use "verga" a lot, it has a lot of meanings depending on the context.

Here is an idea from being annoyed at work:

> No mames a la verga wey!, me parto la madre shambeando todo el puto dia para que vengan éstos vergas a decirme esas shingaderas,puras mamadas al shile cabrón! Amalayón anduviera allá en Sonora asando una carnita con los compas pero aquí ando shingandole y para qué?; y luego con el pinshi calorón que hace aquí!, con ganas de tirarme bishi a una pinshi alberba a la verga!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time for answering this question, and for showing us the niceties of the Sonora way of speaking! Welcome to the site!

Comment: Jajaja esto es perfecto, ¡muchas gracias amigo! Me encanta especialmente palabras y referencias de Sonora, tal como carne asado, compas o bishi. Gracias también por Matadornetwork link, yo lee más interesante artículos ahí. Cuando hacemos esta pelicula, yo escribo URL aquí y tú podrás escuchar nuestro versión de esas palabras :)

Comment: Hehe "Amalayón". This word alone told me you are really from Sonora.

Answer (score 4):

> Hijo de la verga wey, no mames. Pinches mamones de mierda, pinches pendejos con sus putas mamadas, a la putísima chingada. Eso me caga, eso me quema los huevos cabrón, chinguen su reputa madre. Que pinche culero. ¡Chingada madre!

(No soy mexicano pero sí vivo en México)

Edit: Comments on the original sentences.

*¡Hijo de la puta chingadera!*  
Chingadera doesn't fit here & should be replaced by chingada. I don't hear "puta chingada", probably because puta & chingada refer to a similar thing (being a whore). *Hijo de la gran chingada* is usable, & more common - *hijo de tu puta madre* and *hijo de tu chingada madre*. Chingadera is for an object or maybe a situation, a piece of shit / garbage, something fucked up, etc. E.g., *Por fin me deshice de esa chingadera.*

*¡Vete a la verga pinche culero!*  
This is OK. Sending someone to *la verga* and calling someone a *culero* is very common.

*¡No me salgas con tu pendejadas mamón!*  
Also OK but probably using *vengas* en lugar de *salgas*.

*¡Cago en coño de tu puta madre!*  
You are right, sounds castellano. I've never heard any popular curses involving *el coño* in Mexico. It's all about *la verga* here.

Comment: ¡Gracias compañero, eso es muy bonito jajaja! :)