# Is "comprar un argumento" an anglicism derived from "I (don't) buy it"?

Tags: gramática, expresiones

Yesterday listening to a podcast I heard the expression "**No compro ese argumento**" something that I think I have heard before from the person in that video, but I don't think I have heard it only from him.

This person was from Spain. If he had been from an American Spanish-speaking country I would had assumed that "(No) compar ese/un argumento" was a literal translation of "**(I don't) Buy that argument**" and thus an anglicism. But I keep hearing that expression more and more and there is something slightly odd about it.

I don't recall using "comprar ese/un argumento" at all while I was living in Spain. I would have favored "no me lo creo", "no creo que sea cierto" o even the more plain "No estoy de acuerdo". Nevertheless, I see Spaniards using more and more this expression and I wonder if it's due to the influence of the English "I don't buy that argument" or if it actually has been widely used and I never noticed (or even used before, though not widely).

Is "*comprar un/ese argumento*" and anglicism derived from "*I (don't) buy that argument*"? Can we see it being used in old texts or the like, to prove it was used in Spanish since long ago, though maybe not often?

Comment: Yo lo uso con cierta frecuencia y desde hace el suficiente tiempo como para no recordar cuándo lo oí por primera vez. Es una forma de hablar normalizada en mi entorno. Lo que no sé es a cuándo se remonta (de ahí que no responda más que comentario).

Comment: Eso sí, no he encontrado entradas de *te lo compro* con este sentido ni en el [CORPES, CREA ni CORDE](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/24314/1674) (hacía tiempo que no buscaba allí, lo mismo no busqué bien).

Comment: In Argentina we use it a lot, even alone. Somebody proposes a solution and you just say "Compro".

Comment: "Compro", sí, lo del argumento ya no. Es más frecuente hablar de alguien que quiere "vender" alguna idea.

Comment: No creo que sea un anglicismo, es mas como una evolución del lenguaje. Piensa en que te venden algo que no vale la pena y respondes "no te lo compro", puede que en algun punto se halla extendido el uso de esa expresión a contextos donde te tratan de inducir una idea y a ti no te convence.

Comment: I would instead use *no me lo trago*. *Ese cuento no me lo trago*

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for certain where they got it. In Chile, however, we've always used *no lo compro* or *no compro eso*; saying *no compro ese argumento* sounds unidiomatic and we're unlikely to use it. The main use of *comprar*, with this sense, is to *believe*.

Literally speaking, on the other hand, we can say that it's taken from *buy*, used informally in this case. In addition, Spanish-speaking people are used to taking English words and translating them deliberately, so it doesn't come as a surprise they use it in this way.