# Where can I find a platform like conversifi to exchange English lessons for Spanish?

Tags: recursos, aprendizaje

I would like to practice conversing with Spanish speakers in exchange for English. Someone told me about conversify but I have not been able to find it for Spanish. Does anyone else have a website where I can exchange English for Spanish?

Comment: Hello, Jeffrey, and welcome to our site. Please see [Resources for learning Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23617/12637) for information about your request. If you can find your answer there, please tell us so we can mark this question as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: You can getter better resources in [languagelearning.se]

Comment: Learning Arabic,Spanish,French on Facebook allows you to advertise this type of exchange as well as other resources. Hello Talk is a great  free app,allows video/phone calls , texts and  corrections. Tandem is another but not sure if it is free.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about the Spanish language but Spanish language **learning**.

Answer (score -1):

I like using Tandem to talk to people in other languages.