# Looking for a website to essentially proofread my Spanish?

Tags: recursos

I am looking for a check my work website to ask for feedback. I know that this website is not for check my work questions. Just wondering where it might be a good place to go?

Comment: Would it make sense to add another answer to [Resources for Learning Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23617)? I do realize it can be useful for both learners and native speakers who are less confident about their texts.

Comment: @Glorfindel thanks for moving the question back here. We had some debates on whether these questions should be here or in Meta. The current approach is [explained in Meta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2847/1674) after [voting about it](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2740/1674).

Answer (score 2):

In the website: enclave.rae.es
there is a verification tool to check one's Spanish. As they say: "Verificador --
Permite verificar la corrección de cualquier texto a la luz de criterios ortográficos, gramaticales, léxicos y de estilo."

This tool is under the heading:"taller" and then click on "verificador."
or    enclave.rae.es/taller/verificador

This is a paid site offered by the "Real Academia Española." They offer seven days as a trial period. After that, according to the site, it is 2.5 euros per month (that may be charged all at once for a year--I am not sure).

The site has many aids to help learn Spanish--especially it has academic tools.

I am subscribed to that site -- but I have not used it that much. When I was charged I believe it was on an annual basis. They have an automatic renewal process. I disengaged that. I prefer to renew manually, if I wish to renew. It has many good things to use--but I have not used it to its full potential.

Your question about verifying the correction of one's written Spanish will motivate me to use that site more. I never paid too much attention to the verification tool. But it looks like a very good tool. I tested it again just now, by writing some incorrect Spanish--and it seems to work very well. It corrected the text (or signalled errors), and offers various options for words spelled incorrectly.

In that verification tool it seems that one can also load files up to it--so the text in the file can be verified also.

It impresses me as a very good tool.

Of course Microsoft Word can also check Spanish for correction. The RAE site may go beyond what Word can do. I need to check the RAE site out more--especially the verification tool.

You had a good question. Thank you.

Note: I am a new participant on this site. This is the first question I have commented on. I hope I followed all the rules when I offered a comment on this question.

PS I just tried using the verification site again. From what I can see now--it corrects misspellings well and faulty accentuation--but it doesn't seem to correct style too well--or things that may not make sense, such as mixing up a future verb with a time indicator like "ayer". Maybe more artificial intelligence is needed! I will continue to check it out.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a good answer. For additional reference, there is also a review of the tools of Enclave RAE [on our Meta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4344/24236).

Comment: Hello "wimi",

Thank you for your welcome and your encouraging comment.

I also appreciate the link that you sent my way so that I could review what Enclave RAE offers. Though I have had that service for over a year--I am definitely not using it to its full potential.
Thank you again. Much appreciated.
Ray
PS And thank you for your service in moderating the Spanish Stack Exchange. The Stack Exchange for Spanish is an amazing resource.