# Ayuda para aprender español

Tags: español-neutral

As of today, I have very few knowledge regarding Spanish and I would like to be able to establish a conversation with native speakers. Recently, I signed up in a website called preply and booked a lesson with a tutor. However, I consider that everything she said is very advanced for me. What would you advise me to start with?

P.S. I bought a book called *Spanish for grade K-5*. Will this help to improve my Spanish? If not, what can I do to improve my Spanish skills?

Comment: I am afraid this is likely to be closed here as off-topic. There is a site on Language Learning which might be a better fit since the advice you might get would be the same for most languages. When you have learned a bit and have more specific questions then search this site and then ask a question here where we can help you.

Comment: We do maintain a list of resources which you may find helpful https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23617/resources-for-learning-spanish-recursos-para-aprender-espa%c3%b1ol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's amazing that you want to learn Spanish! Spanish is a broad language, and it is spoken in lots of countries. To start learning Spanish, I suggest you:

1. **Enter a class that is related with your knowledge of the language.** It is not the same to join a class that is offered for advanced learners than a class that is directed to people who are starting to learn.
2. **READ.** Seriously, read. After, you have learned some basic aspects of the language, you can start reading easy texts.
3. **Practice.** Practice is your best friend. If you practice the topics that you are learning in class, you could have a better understanding of what they are teaching you in class. You can even use some platforms such as "Quizlet": https://quizlet.com to help you organize yourself.
4. **Don't stress.** If you ever feel that a topic is too hard or you are not understanding, ASK for help. You can ask your teacher, Google the topic that you are struggling with, or ask a friend that speaks Spanish. Remember, ALWAYS ask for help.

Those are the basic things that you need to accomplish while you learn. If you fulfill them, you will be able to learn Spanish in no time.