# Need a good legal glossary

Tags: terminología, recursos, lenguaje-jurídico

I'm looking for a good legal glossary -- could be added to [Resources for learning Spanish / Recursos para aprender español](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23617/9385)

Alternatively a concise introduction to legal concepts and terminology written entirely in Spanish.

Preferably with a Latin American or US focus rather than Iberian.

Comment: There are dictionaries online you can buy. I personally don't think a glossary cuts it most times. You say Latin American or US focus. Here's the real point: The US has a common law system, LA and Spain have what is called the Roman law regime.  Iberian and LA will be the same as they are based on the same legal systems. Also, translating for Spanish speakers **in the US** is not the same as translating Spanish>English or English>Spanish in an international context.

Comment: So my question is: Are you looking for a glossary geared to Hispanics in the US? Many states have them. New Jersey, for example: https://www.njcourts.gov/forms/11783_glossary_spanish.pdf Generally, those are for interpreters. There is not so much "into Spanish" written translation in these contexts but the terminology would be the same.

Comment: @Lambie - thanks, that's a nice one, thanks.  I've applied to be a per diem interpreter.  I've done the written exam and now I'm waiting for COVID to calm down to schedule the oral exam.  I know legal terminology in English, now I have to learn it in Spanish.  I volunteer-interpret for mediation but usually that doesn't involve a lot of legal terminology. / Put the NJ gloss in an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Boy, you're nice. Personally, I never volunteer to interpret. Why? Because most of the lawyers who volunteer are getting paid by their law firms for the pro bono work. By the way, you might want to start out with deposition interpreting that is easier than in a courtroom setting.

Comment: I removed my last comment as it was off-topic but I'm sure you saw it. You can't believe the crap that goes on in this profession. :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the main source for this could be the **Diccionario panispánico del español jurídico**, in this [link](https://dpej.rae.es/), you could find the concepts enterly in Spanish

Answer (score 0):

Here are two sources of information:

[Spanish<>English legal glossary](https://www.ncsc.org/education-and-careers/state-interpreter-certification/legal-glossaries-and-dictionaries)

[Spanish<>English legal glossary](https://www.njcourts.gov/forms/11783_glossary_spanish.pdf)

Most important: :)

How do you plead?

¿Cómo se declara?

Innocent: Inocente

Guilty: Culpable

Comment: ¿No se declara **not guilty** en vez de **innocent**????

Comment: Sí, guilty and not guilty, But I am innocent. No culpable es not guilty.