# What is the best book to learn synonyms?

Tags: recursos

I have been learning Spanish for a couple of years now, but I think that learning synonyms will help me improve quicker.

Comment: Do any of the suggestions in the faq https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23617/resources-for-learning-spanish-recursos-para-aprender-espa%c3%b1ol help you?

Comment: Just learning synonyms is no good. Find one and then find sentences where it is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te recomiendo que uses la RAE, que es el más completo en español (es online). Para libro de papel, si a eso te refieres, te recomiendo el diccionario de sinónimos y antónimos de SM.
[image]

Es muy recomendable, espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 3):

Desde mi punto de vista existen dos autores que están bien.

[image]

**Diccionario de Sinónimos y Antónimos, Dos Tomos de Ángel López García-Molins**

---

[image]

[image]

**Diccionario de sinónimos y antónimos de la lengua española María Moliner**